# how to approach different users that interreact with each other in laravel migration mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, authentication, database-design

I recently took a Laravel course to create my final year project. I had already created the database but with this course things got me a little confused, because Laravel has it's own user table and authorization.
I don't know what or how to create the database relation anymore because I'm so confused right now.

here is what the project is like:

every student has a supervisor, and in the system they upload their tasks or chapter and stuff, only the supervisor will this students progress and files they have uploaded, basically similar to Moodle but only the student's supervisor is able to see it.

the supervisor has many students that they supervise. they can only add tasks, edit task deadlines, and add files for templates and guidelines and add task and edit deadlines for each individual student.

the admin will link the students to the supervisor they are assigned to in the system. and will create chapters, tasks if needed and it's deadlines, and add individual guidelines and templates to each department and level separately.

on very rare times the supervisor can also act as the admin too

note: I will have to user Microsoft Office 365 authentication or the university will take the project and add that later on. this is not decided yet but I have to get this part done

in the course and documentation they use roles to separate each user, so like this

user-->role_user--->role
this is how it's done in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

this is what I did initially.

[image]

UPDATE: I went and made another erd design, a very simple one, I don't know if that one is better and if it will even work.

[image: in this image, a user can have a few roles, after that and admin will input the supervisors id and the student id into the project_user table and link them together, and the project table will take their ids from the project_user table]

the problem that i want to solve is how can i make so that a supervisor can also be an admin at times

UPDATE:
as requested i made some queries in the database

users table
[image: user table]

roles table
[image]

user_roles table
[image]

project table
[image: project table]

Comment: This site frowns on doing homework.

Comment: the question is, should i use the role relation like in the documentation, or should i just go along with what i have done so far? or make a new design where i have a mix of both designs?

Comment: Let's see the queries.

Comment: sorry but queries for the which one exactly? i also made another simple erd design i don't know if that will work, i will update the question

Comment: The connections between project_user and user_role seem wrong.

Comment: what if i were to remove it instead? and just have the project information set as nullable?

Comment: I need to see the queries.

Comment: hello, sorry for the late update, I faced some other issues and had to abandon this one for a while. I updated the question.